# Cell wise operation on data frame, determine precision

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data frame with different data types in it.
I would like to determine precision of float types.
I can select only float64 with this code:

```
df_float64 = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.float64]
```

(not sure why columns with only 'Nan' values are also selected but this is just side note)

Now to determine precision I thing abut such approach:

```
precision = len(cell.split(".")[1]
```

If cell would be a string.

And have output in form of csv with maximum precision for each column.

So having data frame like this:

```
|     A|     B|     C|     D|
|  0.01|0.0923|   1.0|   1.2|
| 100.1| 203.3| 1.093|   1.9|
|   0.0|  0.23|  1.03|   1.0|
```

I would like to to have this:

```
|     A|     B|     C|     D|
|     2|     4|     3|     1|
```

Is this possible using Pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) first for remove `NaNs`
- cast to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)
- loop by columns by [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or `list comprehension` with lambda function
- for each column [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), get second values of list by `str[1]` and get [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html)
- get [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) values - output is `Series`
- convert `Series` to one row DataFrame if necessery

---

```
a = df.fillna(0).astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.split('.').str[1].str.len()).max()
print (a)
A    2
B    4
C    3
D    1
dtype: int64

df = a.to_frame().T
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  2  4  3  1
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.fillna(0).astype(str)
a = [df[x].str.split('.').str[1].str.len().max() for x in df]

df = pd.DataFrame([a], columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  2  4  3  1
```

Comment: Seem to work, I had to remove NaN to work df_na = df.fillna(value=0)

Comment: I have to thank you rather :) One more time you helped me!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for applymap i.e

If you have a dataframe df

```
        A         B      C    D
0    0.01    0.0923  1.000  1.2
1  100.10  203.3000  1.093  1.9
2    0.00    0.2300  1.030  1.0
```

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: len(x.split(".")[-1])).max()).T
```

If you have nan you can use if else i.e

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x:  len(x.split(".")[-1]) if x != 'nan' else 0 ).max()).T
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  2  4  3  1
```

Comment: Glad to help @Submi